# Is it really necessary to implement Gzip to my Html files if they are smaller that 16KB?

Tags: gzip

I am not sure if using gzip is really necessary, or will dramatically speed up my website if I implement it to my html files.

The file is quite small, so I am not sure if users will notice a difference if the webpage is served over gzip.

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

The result depends on the actual contents of your HTML files. I recommend you to try it. Measure the overall page load time and amount of transferred bytes with your browser's developer tools to get evidence.